# How to calculate the inverse of sum of a Kronecker product and a diagonal matrix

Tags: inverse, computational-complexity, diagonalization, floating-point, kronecker-product

I want to calculate the inverse of a matrix of the form  $S = (A\otimes B+C)$, where $A$ and $B$ are symetric and invertible, $C$ is a diagonal matrix with positive elements. Basically if the dimension is high, direct calculation can be expensive. So I wonder if it is possible to speed up the calculation taking advantage of some algebraic structures?

For example, let $A$ be a $m\times m$ matrix and $B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, then we have $(A\otimes B)^{-1}=A^{-1}\otimes B^{-1}$ so that the approximate cost in floating point operations (flops) can be reduced from $7m^3n^3/3$ to $7(m^3+n^3)/3+m^2n^2$.

Since the matrix $S$ also has some special structure, any idea on the efficient calculation of $S^{-1}$?

Many thanks!

- In addition, what about $S^{−1}a$, where $a$ is a $mn\times 1$ vector.

Comment: Do you know whether A, B or C are invertible?  If C is a Kronecker product as well then you can compute the inverse in the style of solving a Sylvester equation.  If S is positive definite you can compute the inverse (or at least solve a linear equation) efficiently using the Conjugate gradient algorithm.

Comment: @Peder Yes, A, B and C are all invertible. C is just a diagonal matrix with only positive main diagonals. But I am not sure if C can be written as a Kronecker product..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that might work well.  Let $C$ have diagonal elements $d_1,\dots,d_{mn}$.  Write
$$
C = d_1 e_1e_1^T + \cdots + d_{mn} e_{mn} e_{mn}^T
$$
Now, we can find the inverse by applying the [Sherman-Morrison formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) (iteratively) $mn$ times.  That is, we've broken the computation into several rank-1 updates.

What's nice is that this allows you to leverage your formula for $(A \otimes B)^{-1}$.  I'm not sure how efficient that will be in practice, but it's a start.

Comment: thanks! It is feasible. But as you have already stated that it might be not efficient. Another concern may be the numerical accuracy, as the algorithm is iterative and we need to calculate the things at each iteration. I wonder if there are some exact formula for this inversion, as the exact formula can be put into the calculation later to avoid numerical error because of plug-in.

Comment: Are the entries of $C$ small relative to the entries of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Also, note that multiplication by $e_i$ is just a row/column extraction.

Comment: May I ask why did you ask about the magnitude of entries? Yes, the special $e_i$ may make the computation faster. I will have a try. Thx!

Comment: @EridkPoliruyt if the $d_i$ are sufficiently small and $A, B$ are [well-conditioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), we can guarantee that there won't be any issues with numerical accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that only works for computing $S^{-1}a$ and only works when S itself is positive definite (which is the case if $A$ and $B$ is positive definite).

The conjugate gradient algorithm computes $x=S^{-1}a$ by doing at most $mn$ multiplications of the form $S x_k$ where $x_0$ is an initial guess.  You can get the exact algorithm from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method.  You have
$$
S x_k = S \mathrm{vec}(X_k) = (A\otimes B + C) \mathrm{vec}(X_k) = \mathrm{vec}(BX_kA^\top + K\odot X_k)
$$
where $\odot$ is the elementwise matrix product, $x_k=\mathrm{vec}(X_k)$ and $C=\mathrm{diag}(\mathrm{vec}(K))$.  Therefore $Sx_k$ can be computed in $m^2n+n^2m+nm$ operations.  Since we at most need to do $mn$ of these vector matrix multiplications the total computation is $\mathcal{O}(m^3n^2+n^3m^2)$, which is at least a little better than $m^3n^3$.  Actually it's a lot better when you consider how much memory the algorithms require -- $\mathcal{O}(m^2+n^2)$ instead of $m^2n^2$.